# How to give margin or align for placeholder in textfield in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

Can anybody tell  How to give margin or align for placeholder in text field in sencha touch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css for this.

Define css in your css file and use it

```
.customField input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        /*color: #2e4bc5;*/
        padding-left:50px;
    }
```

and use like below with cls property.

```
{
  xtype: 'numberfield',
  placeHolder: "enter your contact number",
  cls: 'customField',
  label: 'Contact Number'
 },
```